# What unique information generates a ColdFusion session ID?

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-7, content-delivery-network

I'm using nocache headers to tell a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to not cache the page, but every page request generates a new ColdFusion session ID. So I cannot persist session variables!

If I bypass the CDN, the session is unique per browser on my machine - and will work as normal.

I want to see if the CDN company can do anything to help this situation, but I can't find out how ColdFusion decides to create a new session ID. I suspect the CDN is generating something unique each time, but don't know what.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion writes a `CFTOKEN` and `CFID` cookie (or poss a `JSESSIONID` one, depending on your session setings). Those identify your sessions.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I do not get any cookies when coming through the CDN understandably when cached - but with I don't get it with nocache header either